# linear transformation mapping a rectangle to a parallelepiped?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am puzzled by a statement in Billingsley's "Probability and Measure."
After Theorem 12.2 (If $T:\Re^k\to \Re^k$ is linear and nonsingular, then $A \in \Re^k$ implies that $TA \in \Re^k$ and $\lambda_k(TA)=|\det T| \lambda_k(A)$, where $\lambda_k$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\Re^k$), he states

"Since a parallelepiped is the image of a rectangle under a linear transformation, this formula can be used to compute its volume."

I cannot figure out which linear transformation can map a rectangle to a parallelepiped. Moreover, if $B$ is a rectangle and $TB$ is the corresponding parallelepiped $\lambda_3(B)=0$ and then it would follow $\lambda_3(T B)=0$, that is false.

May it be that is simply an error and that he meant parallelogram?

Comment: Billingsley's statement appears to be  perfectly right in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Maybe the term "rectangle" refers to an arbitrary product of intervals (not just two)?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHoppe,the term parallelepiped is used for a 3D figure. I would be fine with the statement if he had wrote parallelogram.

Comment: @Giovanni Please check B.'s definition of *rectangle*. I presume it's defined in the sense of the comment above, in which case B. is right.

Comment: @user86418, I checked. Indeed he uses rectangle for any arbitrary product of intervals. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe,  I checked. Indeed he uses rectangle for any arbitrary product of intervals. Thanks